# Entity Framework code first - Many to Many - Include conditional

Tags: linq, include, ef-code-first, eager-loading

I have two Entities `Store` and `Catalog`, having many to many relationship using fluent Api. I want to get a Store by `id` with all the catalogs having status equals to "Published".
Below I try to write the following query but not getting the expected results.

```
var store = context.Stores.Include("Catalogs").Where(s => s.StoreID == id && s.Catalogs.Any(c => c.Status == "Published")).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for there is "give me the store with this ID, but only if it has a published catalog" (the "Any" call).

The easiest way to only get published catalogs would be to project them into an anonymous type:

```
var result = (from s in context.Stores
             where s.StoreID == id
             select new
             {
                 Store = s,
                 Catalogs = s.Catalogs.Where(c => c.Status == "Published")
             }).SingleOrDefault();
```

... or, in the fluent interface:

```
var result = context.Stores.Where(st => st.StoreID == id)
                           .Select(s => new 
                           {
                               Store = s,
                               Catalogs = s.Catalogs.Where(c => c.Status == "Published"),
                           }).SingleOrDefault();
```

So `result.Catalogs` holds all the published catalogs that apply to `result.Store`.

Comment: Thanks for the clue i managed to get the result using strongly typed model. I am updating your answer for others.

Comment: @Muhammad I have made the edit by hand to include the fluent style, but still using anonymous types.

Comment: One question i my mind. I think all catalogs of the store will also be loaded using `result.Store.Catalogs` because of `.Include("Catalogs")`

Comment: Oh yeah - I dunno how that got onto the fluent part of the code (it's not on the query-syntax version). I will remove it.